# Org-drill How can you retest yourself on completed / rescheduled drills?

Tags: org-mode, org-drill

As an example say, I run `M-x org-drill` on the spanish.org and mark all of them as 5 for how well I did. All of the drills are rescheduled for 5 days. If I try to run org-drill again I get

```
I did not find any pending drill items.
```

and none of the tests will run again. I get that message running `org-drill-cram` as well. How would I run all the tests regardless of how well I did.

Related question but regarding the philosophy for org-drill, am I suppose to remind myself to check back to the org file on the scheduled date? Or will org-drill prompt me to retest on the scheduled date. (Looking to get some input on other people's workflows with org-drill if possible)